# How to set Kamon log reporter to redirect logs to a log file?

Tags: kamon

I have currently succeeded in setting up kamon log reporter by using the following configuration.

```
   kamon{  modules {    kamon-log-reporter.auto-start = yes   } }
```

I am using the following version of kamon log reporter

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.kamon</groupId>
        <artifactId>kamon-log-reporter_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

How do i redirect the logs to a log file instead of writing them to System.out?